# Using vue-router in Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I want to use use vue-router to route to a new component from a Vuex store. Is it possible to access the router from a Vuex store? I've seen a bunch of threads about it, but nothing that really worked for me... The error below is what I get when I try to use the router.

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_vue_router**.a.push is not a function"

Here's my store:

```
SENTENCE_TRACKER({commit, state}){
  let chosenSentence
  if(state.currSent < state.res.length) {
    chosenSentence = state.res[state.currSent];
    console.log(chosenSentence);
    commit('CHINESE', {chineseData:chosenSentence.chinese})
    commit('ENGLISH', {englishData:chosenSentence.english})
    commit('PINYIN', {pinyinData:chosenSentence.pinyin})
    commit('AUDIO', {audioData:chosenSentence.audio})
    commit('WBW', {wbwData:chosenSentence.wbw})
    state.currSent++
  } else {
     // THIS IS WHERE I'D LIKE TO USE VUE-ROUTER
     router.push({path:'/summary'})
  }
     let arr = []
     state.wbw.map(function(i){
       arr.push('')
     })
     commit('WBW_STATE', {wbwStateData: arr})

     let shuffled = state.wbw.slice(), i, j, k;
     for (i = shuffled.length; i; i--) {
       j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
       k = shuffled[i - 1];
       shuffled[i - 1] = shuffled[j];
       shuffled[j] = k;
     }
     commit('SHUFFLED', {shuffledData: shuffled})
    },
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code for setting up your `router`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I just had to not use the normal `this.$router` syntax in the store and instead just do this: `router.push({name:'summary'})`. Thanks!